# Would somebody like

Tags: american-english

Do AmE speakers use the structure 'would somebody like' in their polite speech or hearing that immediately makes them think their interlocutor is a Briton?
For instance:

> - I’d like two kilos of apples, please.
> - Would you like to dance?
> - What would you like to drink?

and so on.

Comment: No, those are ordinary AmE, too. Except the kilos.

Comment: Thank you @StoneyB. Then I would be greatful if you could tell me how the Americans say this sentence (the first one which as you mentioned is BE) in such a polite way?

Comment: I'd like four pounds of apples, please.

Comment: Oh! Do you mean that just because Americans use 'pound' rather than ('kilo' which is BE), the first one is BE?!

Comment: Yes, that's what he is saying @A-friend. Unless you are in some sort of scientific setting, an American won't say "Kilos." Honestly, even if I were measuring in metric I would say "Kilograms" and never "Kilos" personally.

Comment: But yes, all of those examples are fine apart from the word Kilos.

Comment: It's a bit off topic, but in the US the only common use of the word "kilo" is in the drug trade, as in, "a kilo of cocaine."  "Kilogram" would be readily understood and have no drug connotations, but from my experience (as a chemistry and physics teacher) most Americans would have no clear idea how much two kilograms of apples are.  They could figure it out, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Slight connotation difference.

"Would anyone/anybody like something to drink?" (Expect multiple responses)
"Would somebody pick up that trash!"  (Expect only one response)
"Would someone answer that phone!"  (Expect only one response)

However, in your sentence examples, saying "Would you like" is not comparable meaning to "Would somebody like" (anyone can respond, not just the "you" person)

Answer (score 1):

I've lived in Montana, Texas, and Colorado, and in each state I heard people say they would like something.